# Showing input field blank if the date value from database is 0000--00--00 00:00:00 in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
  $_POST["s_plan"] = $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_start_date;
        $_POST["e_plan"] = $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_end_date;
        $_POST["s_due"] = $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_start_due_date;
        $_POST["e_due"] = $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_end_due_date;
```

This is how i am passing values from my controller for 4 date fields in view code below:

```
<input type="text" name="s_plan" id="s_plan" value="<?php echo set_value('s_plan');?>" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" name="s_due" id="s_due" value="<?php echo set_value('s_due');?>" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" name="e_plan" id="e_plan" value="<?php echo set_value('e_plan');?>" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" name="e_due" id="e_due" value="<?php echo set_value('e_due');?>" class="datepicker" />
```

Now every thing is working but i want that if in database the values of these date fields are `0000--00--00 00:00:00`. that it should not `set_value` on my form. or may be `echo ""`;

Updated:

```
$_POST["s_plan"] = ($data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_start_date != "0000-00-00") ? $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_start_date : "";
        $_POST["e_plan"] = ($data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_end_date != "0000-00-00") ? $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_end_date : "";
        $_POST["s_due"] = ($data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_start_due_date != "0000-00-00") ? $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_start_due_date : "";
        $_POST["e_due"] = ($data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_end_due_date != "0000-00-00") ? $data['tasks_detail'][0]->nt_end_due_date : "";
```

Now when i put condition in my controller as above. Now nothing is being shown in view even if the date field has a date value

Comment: you have to compare values based on your condition.

Comment: i tried let me show you the way i tried to validate. please check updated part of question

Comment: do your condition check in view with `set_value()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I wrote a Function for this the other Day:]

```
function ctd($datetime, $format=false, $displayzero=false){
     $timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
     if(!$format){
        $format = 'd.m.Y'; // <---------- your default Date-Format
     }
     if($timestamp > strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')){
        return date($format, $timestamp);
     }else{
         if($displayzero){
            return str_replace(1, 0, date($format, strtotime('0001-01-01 00:00:00')));
         }else{
            return false;
         }
     }
}
```